# Syntax error in css code

Tags: html, eclipse, css, aptana

```
border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
```

Aptana 3.0.6 gives me the following error `"too many values or values are not recognized"` for both the above line. What is the correct syntax

Comment: Syntax appears to be correct, maybe Aptana doesn't check against CSS3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching on Aptana's website revealed the following known bug:

["color: rgba(...);" causes a CSS validation error](http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-3407)

It also states that it has been fixed in the latest version of the software (3.0.7).